# Buy macbook pro 17 from amazon vs apple?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation

I'm about to purchase the new macbook pro 17 from amazon.  $134 less than from Apple and no tax means almost $400 is saved...  amazon only has the base model without any upgrades, but that's what I wanted anyway.

Any reason to spend the extra money and go with Apple directly?  Is there a better place to buy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend buying an official Apple.com refurb - you'll likely save more than from Amazon and they often have very current models.  The machine will be indistinguishable from new, aside from the packaging and comes with a full warranty.

Put the savings towards buying cheaper Applecare from Amazon :)

You can follow stock availability here: http://refurb-tracker.com

Comment: Even though I ended up purchasing from amazon, I gave you the credit as I would've purchased refurb if it was available...  wasn't aware of this option.

Comment: My last MacBook Pro 17" was bought as a refurb from the Apple Store. I've been using it for four years developing commercial software.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to choose between the **Apple Online Store** (not the Apple Store as Philip implied) and **Amazon**. If that is the case, you don't have any advantages when buying directly from Apple (only if you are an educator, student or pupil - because you will be able to purchase from the Apple Education Store then). Go to Amazon if it is cheaper there.

If you're thinking about choosing between an **Apple Store** and any **Online Store** you have the advantages mentioned by Philip.

Comment: +1 for reading the question a different way than me and for a very valid point as a result.

Answer (score 2):

If anything, buying the laptop from the Apple store will give you a level of customer service that no other store can match. They'll probably help you get it set up, registered, and all that if you ask. That, and the certain cache that comes from walking out an Apple store with brand new kit under your arm. Beyond that, there's really not much you can buy there that can't be had for cheaper elsewhere.